# MediaElement not playing after changing position

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have a video player which downloads a video file in chunks. After a chunk of 1MB has been downloaded, an event is called giving the MediaElement its source, and making it play. Whilst the video is being played, the rest of the 1MB chunks are downloaded until the file is complete. 
If only 1MB of the video is downloaded, the **playback time is equal to 17 seconds**(This will come in later).
When the file is completely downloaded, permission is given to the user to change the position of the video or seek it. If the user seeks to a position under or equal to 17 seconds, the MediaElement will change its position and keep on playing, however if the user seeks to a position greater than 17s, the video freezes.
This could be for the fact that the MediaElement has buffered only 1MB of the video so it'll only seek withing that timeframe, but it doesn't make sense because if I let it play without interruption, it'll play the whole video without any problem. Can someone tell me whats going on?

Code:

```
private void downloadchunks()
 for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
 {
  WriteStream = new System.IO.FileStream(DownloadLocation, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
  //request and receive a response of 1MB of a file
  rpstream = response.GetResponseStream();
  byte[] buffer;
  using (var SReader = new MemoryStream())
  {
     rpstream.CopyTo(SReader);
     buffer =SReader.ToArray();
     WriteStream.Seek(WritePos,SeekOrigin.Begin);
     WriteStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     WriteStream.Close();
  }
  if (i==1)
   {
    PlayVideo();
   }
 }
private void PlayVideo()
{
  MediaElement.Source = new uri(DownloadLocation);
  MediaElement.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Just create a dummmy file before you assign it to the MediaElement, and then start the download.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(location, new byte[filesize]);
```